# c++ template class operator<< overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-classes

I am having problem when trying to overload the `<<` operator of a template class, where I receive the `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` error. The code is as follows:

```
template <class T> 
struct subvec {

    T vec[NDIMS];
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const subvec<T>&);
};
...
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const subvec<T>& s) { 
    ...
    return output;
}
...
template subvec<int>;
...
int main() {
    subvec<int> S(0);
    cout << S;
    return;
}
```

All the codes are in the same .cpp file. It compiles fine, but seem to have a linking problem with the `cout<<S` line. If I comment it out, everything else is fine. 
I have searched a few other posts regarding similar problems, but did not find an answer. The only way I can make it work is to copy the definition of `operator<<` into the definition of the `struct subvec<T>` instead of putting it outside. But my definition of `operator<<` is still in the same file. How should I resolve this? I eventually have to separate out a header file anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that the friend is not a template, so the compiler belives it is a different operator.

Comment: Thank you! That is THE problem!